# How to mock function returning void task

Tags: c#, asynchronous

I have a function

```
public Task DoSomethingAsync();
```

which I want to mock for testing purposes.

What is the right way to implement the return value of such a method. If it would return `Task<int>` or something, I would use `Task.FromResult<int>(5);`

I could do

```
public async void DoSomethingAsync()
{
//implementation
}
```

This however lacks the await operator and will (at least with Resharper) be underlined.

What is the correct way to return a task here?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

All you need to do is to return a `Task` and (surprise! :-)) `Task<T>` derives from `Task`, *it is a* `Task`. See this [reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd321424(v=vs.110).aspx).

So just return a `bool` (or anything else):

`return Task.FromResult(true);`

You could also return a [completed](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task.completedtask(v=vs.110).aspx) `Task` by using:

`return Task.CompletedTask;`

(Note: the above is only available as of .NET 4.6)

Comment: Thanks! `FromResult` works fine. I cannot find `Task.CompletedTask`.  I use `using System.Threading;` and `using System.Threading.Tasks`. Am I missing something?

Comment: `System.Threading.Tasks.Task.CompletedTask`should work (with .NET 4.6).

Comment: It says: Cannot Access internal Property 'CompletedTask' here.

Comment: Are you building with .NET 4.6? Could be that it is `internal` in older versions.

Comment: Version 4.6.01055

Comment: According to the reference source it clearly is `public`: http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/threading/Tasks/Task.cs,1650

Answer (score 4):

You can return `Task.CompletedTask` (.net 4.6 required) or simply `Task.FromResult(true)`

The idea is just to return a `Task`

Answer (score 0):

If it is just the mocking you wish implement, create an interface to be used your class:

```
public interface IDoStuff
{
    Task DoSomethingAsync();
}

public class MyDoStuff : IDoStuff
{
    public Task DoSomethingAsync()
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

Then simply create a mock with the interface IDoStuff and mock the method.

Comment: Thank you. My question aimed for something different, but is answered!